# loading urls automatically

Tags: php, javascript, url

I have text file containing 10000 URls(generated from web crawler)
Is there any way to load these URLs automatically in the browser
(I instrumented the browser to generate asts and that is whole point of loading some random bunch of urls which I've got from web crawler)

Comment: is there a way? YES. but what have you tried?

Comment: Some input-emulating scripting like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) would probably work without much hassle at all.

Comment: I wonder which browser will open 10000 tabs at once, obviously this question is a hoax.

Comment: Do you want to load them sequentially or all at the same time. The latter may well be impossible due to browser memory issues.
Perhaps if you give a little more detail as to what you want to achieve people would be more willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

What about, creating page with *iframe*, load these URIs in *textarea* and then run script which take random ones and send it in time interval to the *iframe src* ?